# How to compare two time values in all formats using js?

Tags: javascript

I need to compare two time values in string type. It may be in following format,

> =6:12>7:12 => False
>
> =6:12 PM >7:12 AM => True
>
> = 4/19/2017 6:12 PM > 4/19/2017 7:12 AM => True

like excel.

Can you please suggest me, how to achieve my scenario using JS

Comment: 6:12 and even 6:12 PM are not valid `Date` values. Usually time comparison is done with `Date`s in javascript, so try to convert to that first.

Comment: @JohnVandivier thanks for suggestion.how to convert this 6:12 in date format also need to consider all other date format while converting the this time to date conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no native way to handle time's so you would need to make your own function to convert the timestamp into a unit that can be compared, in this instance I used seconds, but you could use milliseconds.

You have also shown a date stamp, which you can use the `Date` object to convert the timestamp into milliseconds which can be compared.

```js
const timeToSeconds = s => {
  const m = s.match(/(\d{1,2})\:(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)*/)
  return (
    (parseInt(m[1]) * 60) + 
    (parseInt(m[2])) + 
    (m[3] === 'PM' ? 12 * 60 : 0)
  )
}

console.log(
  timeToSeconds('6:12') > timeToSeconds('7:12')
)

console.log(
  timeToSeconds('6:12 PM') > timeToSeconds('7:12 AM')
)

console.log(
  new Date('4/19/2017 6:12 PM').getTime() > new Date('4/19/2017 7:12 PM').getTime()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates to timestamps, then you can compare them using the `>` operator.